# Magento Paypal Configuration button is disabled

Tags: configuration, paypal

[image: paypalDasabled]
Hello All,

I am trying to configure paypal on my magento store and all paypal options are disabled (the button is grey and non-responsive)

I have relocated this store prior to setting up paypal, but this is the first and only time that this has happened to me. I also have a pending reindex that needs to happen (but that's in the too hard basket atm because it looks like I need to do it through SSH)

Does anyone know how to get it working? :)

Answer (score 2):

You need to fill all your store information like **VAT Number, Store Contact Telephone, country, Default Country** in

Magento Admin ->system-> configuration->General

I hope it will work..

Answer (score 2):

I would assume, that magento thinks, that Paypal is not available in Australia? Try to change the country, it might work.